# Is there a way to use the NHibernate session to figure out if changes need to be written to db?

Tags: nhibernate, c#-3.0, lazy-loading

I'm using NHibernate here with C#. I have a cache of nhibernate objects that have lazily loaded objects inside of those that might have changes written to them. I need a way to determine if there are changes that need to be saved. It's quite a lot of effort to set flags when one little thing changes and also quite annoying to compare a cache with a copy of an original (because of the lazy loading).

Just wondering if there's a way I can use the current session object to know if it has pending changes that are about to be written to the db, this is so that I can have a 'do you want to save' prompt if in fact there are changes. I can't autosave, the customer demands a save button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NHibernate.ISession` exposes an `IsDirty()` method so you should be able to check that.

Comment: Thanks,

That's what I'm looking for. It's reading dirty without me changing anything (that I know of) so I've got some debugging to do. Ah the nhibernate journey continues. Thanks!